# Laravel Sanctum and SPA confusion - session regenerate problem

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, laravel-sanctum

Ok, so very weird issue I have. I followed the sanctum documentation with authenticating SPA powered by Laravel API. I am using NuxtJS first-party SPA with Laravel 8 API.

Now when I made the call to the login enpoint after getting the CSRF token I am getting following 500 error from laravel.

```
{message: "Session store not set on request.", exception: "RuntimeException",…}
exception: "RuntimeException"
file: "/srv/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php"
line: 515
message: "Session store not set on request."
trace: [{file: "/srv/app/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/Auth/SanctumLoginController.php", line: 41,…},…]
```

This is the login controller

```php
public function login(Login $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->toArray())) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return $this->okResponse();
        }

        return $this->unauthorizedResponse();
    }
```

And this line causes the error

`$request->session()->regenerate();`

Now these are my API middleware

```php
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

To my understanding Sanctum is supposed to be a hybrid that allows using sessions to authenticate SPA with my Laravel API. This middleware on the top of the list is supposed to allow sessions but there is something wrong here obviously.

I also understand that I should leave my Login controller in the API routes.

It confuses me a bit. I found a post saying that I should add this  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to the middleware array in Kernel but the documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Could anyone explain to me what is up and if I understand all of that correctly?

Comment: api routes don't use the session because API consumers don't typically bother storing and resending cookies. If you need the session don't use API routes. SPAs work just fine when using web routes

Comment: But isn't that what Sanctum documentation suggests?

Comment: Check the notice below that says *You are free to write your own /login endpoint; however, you should ensure that it authenticates the user using the standard, session based authentication services that Laravel provides. Typically, this means using the web authentication guard.* I think this means you should do `Auth::guard('web')->attempt` and `session()->regenerate()` (possibly)

Comment: You're genius! I think you are right again (I think you helped me in the past). I will try this out first thing in the morning! How could I miss it 

Comment: @apokryfos Also do I understand the flow correctly? First auth with web guard => then on each request I will attach my session ID from cookie and card token => the extra middleware on API will just handle that as if it was normal web session not API call right?

Comment: The sanctum middleware seems to be responsible for managing cookies (including the session cookie) as well as starting the session. However I *think* API routes by default use the API authentication guard so you'd need to explicitly specify the web guard whenever you want to use the authenticated user

Comment: That makes sense. Yeah it does use API guard by default. I will use web one for logging in the user and I will just lean upon Laravels mechanisms to handle sessions with API endpoints. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I finally had time to look at it today, but no luck I', afraid, I will just keep digging. I keep getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**config/sanctum.php**

Check to see if localhost:8000 exists.

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
  '%s%s',
  'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
  env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
))),
```

**.env**

```
// + 
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000
```

**JS**

Please send with csrf-token.

```js
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api',
  withCredentials: true,
});

  const getUsers = () => {
    http.get('/users').then((res) => {
      setUsers(res.data);
    })
  }

// Methods except get
  const postUser = (data) => {
    http.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then((res) => {
    http.post('/user',data).then((res) => {
    })
  })
```